# how can i begin scroll at the bottom of a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to know if its possible to make this scrollbar to start at the very bottom a of div
http://enscrollplugin.com/

```
<div id="contentleft>
  <ul>
    <li><p>some content here...</p></li>
    <li><p>some content here...</p></li>
    <li><p>some content here...</p></li>
    <li><p>some content here...</p></li>
    <li><p>some content here...</p></li>
    <li><p>some content here...</p></li>
    <li><p>some content here...</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $('#contentleft').enscroll({
        showOnHover: true,
        verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
        verticalHandleClass: 'handle3',
        scrollIncrement: 15,
        easingDuration: 20
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's invalid markup; you're missing the `ul` or `ol` around your `li`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure...

```
$("#contentleft").scrollTop($("#contentleft").prop("scrollHeight"));
```

This line sets the scroll top offset to the scroll height (the total scrollable height of the element).

Comment: i tried this but it doesnt show the scrollbar and it still starts at the top